# Destroy an object only by its user creator in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have updated the code spec code.

What I seek is to destroy a record only with the same user that has created it.
I've tried in the view section and it seems to be working, but the Rspec is throwing me some errors.
Can anyone please tell me how to do a correct spec?

Thanks

My Record model:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Associations
  belongs_to :user

  # Validations
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

My Record factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :record do

    user
  end
end
```

My Record controller:

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_record, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_permission, only: [:destroy]

  def destroy
    @record.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "The record was deleted successfully"
    redirect_to @record
  end

  private

    def require_permission
      if current_user != Record.find(params[:id]).user
        flash[:notice] = "Permission required"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
end
```

My record spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe RecordsController do
  let(:record) { create(:record) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }




  describe "#destroy" do
    let!(:record) { create(:record) }

#UPDATED
    login_user

    it "deletes the record" do
     expect {
      delete :destroy, id: record.id, :record => {:user => record.user}
     }.to change(Record, :count).by(-1)

     expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("The record was deleted successfully")
    end
  end
end
```

UPDATE 2

rails_helper.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'devise'


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller

end
```

at spec/support/controller_macros.rb

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin) # Using factory girl as an example
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      #user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

My errors:

```
  #destroy
    deletes the record (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) RecordsController#destroy deletes the record
     Failure/Error: expect {
       expected #count to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0
```

Comment: `:record => {:user => @record.user}` it should be `:record => {:user => record.user}`

Comment: give this instead :     Failure/Error: expect {
       expected #count to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0

Answer (score 1):

you use `@record` but you let `record` that's why in error `@record` is nil

```
it "deletes the record" do
      expect {
        delete :destroy, id: record.id, :record => {:user => record.user}
      }.to change(Record, :count).by(-1)

      expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("The record was deleted successfully")
    end
```

Comment: I think the count code is correct - after deleting a record there should be one less.

Comment: gave me this error instead : Failure/Error: expect { expected #count to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0

Comment: Hi Rajarshi, it seems that Rspec is giving me the same error! I am using devise to manage the users, hope this info helps. Feel free to ask something that could help you to solve this issue.